# Capture and place multiple dataframe columns, side by side into new csv file with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am able to capture multpile columns from panadas dataframes. But I am not able to take each of those columns, and one by one, side by side, place and save them into a csv file, that can later be opened in excel.

```
for f in rest_of_files:
    get_averages = pd.read_csv(f)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(get_averages)
    got_averages = df1.loc[:, ['Average']]
    print(got_averages)
    got_averages.to_csv("test.csv", columns=[], axis=1)
```

I've also tried using concatinate. It seems I can intialize the data frame iteration correctly to take each column one by one, without them overwriting each other.

Comment: Are you just looking to transpose your got_averages? `print(got_averages.T)` <-- Does this look like your desired result?

Comment: It not waht I need, but the outcome is the same. Each iteration within the loop overwrites the last when saved to a file. I need a way for each column to be saved, not just the last in the loop.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to read in multiple `CSV` files, extract the 'Average` column from each one, and create a new `CSV` with all of these combined?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The final csv would contain each 'Average' column from the multiple files. In the code above, all of the 'Average' columns have been extracted into the variable `got_avarages`. The print function will output all of the columns,

Comment: I did just find that you can use append mode `got_averages.to_csv("test.csv", mode='a')`. However this lists the columns vertically one after another in a single column. I'd need side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to be sure without some test data, but what about this:

```py
dfs = []
for f in rest_of_files:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(f)['Average'])
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

Comment: I thought you needed to use something like `iloc` first in order to capture the columns, but within `pd.read_csv` you can take the columns by name?

Comment: `loc[]/iloc[]` are for "location based indexing" where as accessing with normal indexing `[]` works just as well for many situations. [See the Docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#basics)